# What are these utensils?

Tags: utensils

A friend of mine is on vacation and found these in their condo. I love to cook and now I have to know what kind of utensils these are. Please Help.[[image: found in a kitchen what are they?[1]]

Comment: To be completely honest, I'll bet they are just salad tongs.

Comment: Are they toothpick sized or salad tong sized?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think they are for salads.  Maybe some kind of scooper for melons or fruit, with ability to "carve" at other end?